# cassandra filtering on an indexed column isn't working

Tags: cassandra

I'm using (the latest version of) Cassandra nosql dbms to model some data.

I'd like to get a count of the number of active customer accounts in the last month.

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE active_accounts
(
    customer_name   text, 
    account_name    text, 
    date            timestamp, 
    PRIMARY KEY ((customer_name, account_name))
);
```

So because I want to filter by date, I create an index on the date column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON active_accounts (date);
```

When I insert some data, Cassandra automatically updates data on any existing primary key matches, so the following inserts only produce two records:

```
insert into active_accounts (customer_name, account_name, date) Values ('customer2', 'account2', 1418377413000);
insert into active_accounts (customer_name, account_name, date) Values ('customer1', 'account1', 1418377413000);
insert into active_accounts (customer_name, account_name, date) Values ('customer2', 'account2', 1418377414000);
insert into active_accounts (customer_name, account_name, date) Values ('customer2', 'account2', 1418377415000);
```

This is exactly what I'd like - I won't get a huge table of data, and each entry in the table represents a unique customer account - so no need for a select distinct.

The query I'd like to make - is how many distinct customer accounts are active within the last month say:

```
 Select count(*) from active_accounts where date >= 1418377411000 and date <= 1418397411000 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

In response to this query, I get the following error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator"
```

What am I missing; isn't this the purpose of the Index I created?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table design in Cassandra is extremely important and it must match the kind of queries that you are trying to preform. The reason that Cassandra is trying to keep you from performing queries on the date column, is that any query along that column will be extremely inefficient.

**Table Design - Model your queries**

One of the main reasons that Cassandra can be fast is that it partitions user data so that most( 99%)
of queries can be completed without contacting all of the nodes in the cluster. This means less network traffic, less disk access, and faster response time. Unfortunately Cassandra isn't able to determine automatically what the best way to partition data. The end user must determine a schema which fits into the C* datamodel and allows the queries they want at a high speed.

```
CREATE TABLE active_accounts
(
   customer_name   text, 
   account_name    text, 
   date            timestamp, 
   PRIMARY KEY ((customer_name, account_name))
);
```

This schema will only be efficient for queries that look like

SELECT timestamp FROM active_accounts where customer_name = ? and account_name = ?

This is because on the the cluster the data is actually going to be stored like

```
node 1: [ ((Bob,1)->Monday), ((Tom,32)->Tuesday)]
node 2: [ ((Candice, 3) -> Friday), ((Sarah,1) -> Monday)]
```

The PRIMARY KEY for this table says that data should be placed on a node based on the hash of the combination of CustomerName and AccountName. This means we can only look up data quickly if we have both of those pieces of data. Anything outside of that scope becomes a batch job since it requires hitting multiple nodes and filtering over all the data in the table.

To optimize for different queries you need to change the layout of your table or use a distributed analytics framework like Spark or Hadoop.

An example of a different table schema that might work for your purposes would be something like

```
CREATE TABLE active_accounts
(
    start_month     timestamp,
    customer_name   text, 
    account_name    text, 
    date            timestamp, 
    PRIMARY KEY (start_month, date, customer_name, account_name)
);
```

In this schema I would put the timestamp of the first day of the month as the partitioning key and date as the first clustering key. This means that multiple account creations that took place in the same month will end up in the same partition and on the same node. The data for a schema like this would look like

```
node 1: [ (May 1 1999) -> [(May 2 1999, Bob, 1), (May 15 1999,Tom,32)]
```

This places the account dates in order within each partition making it very fast for doing range slices between particular dates. Unfortunately you would have to add code on the application side to pull down the multiple months that a query might be spanning. This schema takes a lot of (dev) work so if these queries are very infrequent you should use a distributed analytics platform instead.

For more information on this kind of time-series modeling check out:

http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

Modeling in general:

http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/cassandra-day-denver-2014-40328174
http://www.slideshare.net/johnny15676/introduction-to-cql-and-data-modeling

Spark and Cassandra:

http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-apache-spark-and-cassandra/

**Don't use secondary indexes**

Allow filtering was added to the cql syntax to prevent users from accidentally designing queries that will not scale. The secondary indexes are really only for use by those do analytics jobs or those C* users who fully understand the implications. In Cassandra the secondary index lives on every node in your cluster. This means that any query that requires a secondary index necessarily will require contacting every node in the cluster. This will become less and less performant as the cluster grows and is definitely not something you want for a frequent query.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Modeling is without a doubt one of the most misunderstood aspects of Cassandra.

Comment: Your answer assumes that I care about query speed; I don't; I care about insert speed.  My queries will be low volume and I'm not concerned if they take a long time.

Comment: Use of distributed analytics framework (spark or hadoop) seems like overkill for a problem like this

Comment: Faking a primary key to select the node a record is stored on is fair advice; but where do you draw the line with  if you wanted to support queries that cover a quarter time period for example?  At some point the data is going to be spread over multiple nodes; doesn't that bring us back to square one?

Comment: Square 1 is A Full Table scan, or A full secondary index scan and then thousands of partition scans (one for every pair of account_id,customer_id)

In the schema I proposed it only requires directly retrieving at most 5 partitions to cover the entire 3 month duration. 
Retrieving several partitions directly allows this pattern to scale much more efficiently. 

But if you have so little data that any of this seems like overkill Cassandra may not be the right solution for your needs.

Comment: One other solution, if you have a minimal amount of data you could just store it all in a single partition but again if you are doing this you don't really gain any of the benefits Cassandra offers.

Comment: Faking a hash to locate data on one node, only for this to break once a query requires that data be pulled from multiple nodes - this complicates the table design and only seems to help for small time periods.  Our initial data sets will be performing around 10 inserts per second, but we expect this to increase over time; but we have a small number of tables.